# How to create matrix output pattern with array 2D in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a little difficulty in programming in C ++ to make patterned output using 2D arrays, I make the output like a matrix like this:
input 4 (for column 4 & row 4)

```
I I I I
0 0 I 0
0 I 0 0
I I I I
```

I've tried this my programmed. For the top and bottom rows I've managed to change the value to 1

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int elemen[100][100], n, i, j, k;
    
    cout <<"input element = ";
    cin >>n;
    
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
            elemen[0][j] = 1;
            elemen[n-1][j] = 1;
            elemen[n-i][n-j] = 1;           
            cout <<elemen[i][j]<<" ";
        }   
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
}
```

but the output that occurs in the **above program** is like this:

```
I I I I
0 0 0 0
0 0 I I
I I I I
```

whereas logically it is correct, and I've tried it on non-input arrays.whereas logically it is correct, and I've tried it on non-input arrays. because if we input the array element = 5, then the loop will automatically reduce the value of 5 one by one. Is there anyone who can help, sorry if you do not understand, because I am currently still learning to hone my logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
      for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
            if (i == 0 || i == n-1 || i == n-j-1)
                elemen[i][j] = 1;
            else
                elemen[i][j] = 0;
            ...
       }
       ...
  }
```

- `i = 0` gives you the top row
- `i = n-1` gives you the bottom row
- `i = n-j-1` gives you reverse diagonal

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are actually using `elemen` for anything else than printing this pattern, I suggest dropping it and print the pattern directly.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::size_t n = 4;
    
    std::cout << std::string(n, 'I') << '\n';

    for(std::size_t i=1; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        std::cout
            << std::string(n - i - 1, '0') 
            << 'I'
            << std::string(i, '0')
            << '\n'
        ; 
    }

    std::cout << std::string(n, 'I') << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
IIII
00I0
0I00
IIII
```